# Nested struct on json returns null

Tags: go

I have the following JSON response

```
{
    "data": {
        "app": {
            "name": "api"
        },
        "client": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "plan": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "ssj892"
                }
            }
        ],
        "user": {
            "email": "test@example.com",
        }
    }
}
```

And the following struct

```
Response struct {
    Data       Data   `json:"data"`
}

Data struct {
    User User `json:"user"`
}

User struct {
    Email       string                 `json:"email"`
    Client      Client                 `json:"client"` // has fields, but no data
    // Client []Client `json:"client"` // null
    // Client *Client `json:"client"` // null
}

Client struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
    Plan Plan `json:"plan"`
}

Plan struct {
    Id       int           `json:"id"`
    Name     string        `json:"name"`
}
```

go lang code

```
defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
        res := &Response{}
        err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(Response)
```

Now, why could it be the client is returning a blank record? I could not figure out what I missed. I tried []Client on the struct since client can return multiple ids, but it's returning a null instead. Any help is much appreciated.

```
...
    "client": {
        "id": 0,
        "plan": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "",
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: `client` and `user` are at the same level but your structs try to have `client` inside `user`. As for why you get empty fields, these are the zero values. Try [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) if you're not sure how to setup your structs.

Comment: oh my. My eyes must be tired :(. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JSON, "client" is inside "data", but not inside "user"
So, your structures should be like below

```
Data struct {
    User User `json:"user"`
    Client      []Client                 `json:"client"` // has fields, but no data
    // Client Client `json:"client"` // null
    // Client *Client `json:"client"` // null
}

User struct {
    Email       string                 `json:"email"`
}
```